# When I pass dynamic color value from JSON into BarSeries, devextreme bar chart does not recognize them and make all bars black

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devextreme

I have built a data visualizer using ReactJS and `@devexpress` and `@material-ui`. The chart currently looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the bars to render with dynamic colours, which are present in the following JSON (`bar_color`)

```
[
    {
      "id": 8,
      "place": "Valley Of Flowers",
      "search": 2048,
      "bar_color": "#82b507"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "place": "Bali Pass",
      "percent": 11,
      "bar_color": "#025596"
    },
    ...
]
```

Here is the full component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import { BarSeries, Animation, EventTracker } from "@devexpress/dx-react-chart";

export default class PlaceSearchData extends Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
       <Paper>
          <Chart data={items}>
            <ArgumentAxis />
            <ValueAxis max={10} />

            <BarSeries
              valueField="search"
              argumentField="place"
              color="bar_color" // I want this to be dynamically assigned from the JSON data
            />
            <Title text="Place wise search (top 6)" />
            <Animation />
            <EventTracker />
            <Tooltip />
          </Chart>
       </Paper>    
    );
  }
}
```

But all bar colours are black!

However, if I put a specific colour code, all bars render with that colour, i.e.

```
<BarSeries
   valueField="search"
   argumentField="place"
   color="#82b507"
/>
```

Is there any way that I can pass the colour of each bar dynamically?
I am using https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/chart/docs/reference/bar-series/ as the reference point.

Comment: Please take the time to remove everything that is not related to the question. The `material-ui` is not relevant here. Also the `axios` request. Clean up the question and it will be much easier to help.

Comment: @Dekel I have cleaned up the quesion. Please let me know if this is OK now.

Comment: It seems like the `devexpress/dx-react-chart` lib support color per series (and in your case you have only 1 series, this means only 1 color). I'm not sure there is a simple way to do what you are looking for with this lib.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a solution too, I found the solution:
one must use `<Palette scheme={shema} />` just after the
`<Chartdata={data}>`
Attention, do not put after for example :
`<PieSeries valueField="area" argumentField="country" />`
otherwise it won't work :) and it only recognizes colors in decimal
`<Palette scheme={['#d72e3d', '#249e3d', '#ffb90c', '#1698af', '#616a72']} />`